# Removing Checkout Steps in Sylius

Tags: sylius

I'm working on removing both the shipping and the payment method steps from checkout in Sylius. There is a guide on how to remove the shipping step from checkout included in the Sylius docs here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/checkout.html

I've followed this guide and made additional changes to remove the payment method step as well (my shop will always use one payment method, no need for the user to select this). What's happening is that when I click next on the 'Address' step, I'm taken to the 'Complete' step, but then I'm immediately redirected back to the 'Address' step again, without error. My presumption is that I'll need to make the system aware of which shipping and which payment methods are to be used, but I don't see that code in the Sylius documentation anywhere.

Here are my changes:

app/Resources/SyliusCoreBundle/config/app/state_machine/sylius_order_checkout.yml:

> ```
>     states:
>         cart: ~
>         addressed: ~
>         completed: ~
>     transitions:
>         address:
>             from: [cart, addressed]
>             to: addressed
>         complete:
>             from: [payment_selected]
>             to: completed
> ```

I then ran this command, as suggested, to verify the state machine updates:

> php bin/console debug:config winzou_state_machine

I can successfully see the two steps are removed in my sylius_order_config:

```
 sylius_order_checkout:
        class: Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Order
        property_path: checkoutState
        graph: sylius_order_checkout
        state_machine_class: Sylius\Component\Resource\StateMachine\StateMachine
        states:
            cart: null
            addressed: null
            completed: null
        transitions:
            address:
                from:
                    - cart
                    - addressed
                to: addressed
            complete:
                from:
                    - payment_selected
                to: completed
```

app/config/config.yml:

```
sylius_shop:
    checkout_resolver:
        route_map:
            cart:
                route: sylius_shop_checkout_address
            addressed:
                route: sylius_shop_checkout_complete
```

app/Resources/SyliusShopBundle/views/Checkout/_steps.html.twig:

```
{% if active is not defined or active == 'address' %}
    {% set steps = {'address': 'active', 'complete': 'disabled'} %}
{% else %}
    {% set steps = {'address': 'completed', 'complete': 'active'} %}
{% endif %}

<div class="ui four steps">
    <a class="{{ steps['address'] }} step" href="{{ path('sylius_shop_checkout_address') }}">
        <i class="map icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">{{ 'sylius.ui.address'|trans }}</div>
            <div class="description">{{ 'sylius.ui.fill_in_your_billing_and_shipping_addresses'|trans }}</div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="{{ steps['complete'] }} step" href="{{ path('sylius_shop_checkout_complete') }}">
        <i class="checkered flag icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">{{ 'sylius.ui.complete'|trans }}</div>
            <div class="description">{{ 'sylius.ui.review_and_confirm_your_order'|trans }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app/Resources/SyliusShopBundle/config/routing/checkout.yml:

```
# This file is a part of the Sylius package.
# (c) Paweł Jędrzejewski

sylius_shop_checkout_start:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: sylius_shop_checkout_address

sylius_shop_checkout_address:
    path: /address
    methods: [GET, PUT]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.order:updateAction
        _sylius:
            event: address
            flash: false
            template: SyliusShopBundle:Checkout:address.html.twig
            form:
                type: sylius_checkout_address
                options:
                    customer: expr:service('sylius.context.customer').getCustomer()
            repository:
                method: find
                arguments: [expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart()]
            state_machine:
                graph: sylius_order_checkout
                transition: address
            redirect:
                route: sylius_shop_checkout_complete
                parameters: []
#
#sylius_shop_checkout_select_shipping:
#    path: /select-shipping
#    methods: [GET, PUT]
#    defaults:
#        _controller: sylius.controller.order:updateAction
#        _sylius:
#            event: select_shipping
#            flash: false
#            template: SyliusShopBundle:Checkout:selectShipping.html.twig
#            form: sylius_checkout_select_shipping
#            repository:
#                method: find
#                arguments: [expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart()]
#            state_machine:
#                graph: sylius_order_checkout
#                transition: select_shipping
#            redirect:
#                route: sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment
#                parameters: []
#
#sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment:
#    path: /select-payment
#    methods: [GET, PUT]
#    defaults:
#        _controller: sylius.controller.order:updateAction
#        _sylius:
#            event: payment
#            flash: false
#            template: SyliusShopBundle:Checkout:selectPayment.html.twig
#            form: sylius_checkout_select_payment
#            repository:
#                method: find
#                arguments: [expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart()]
#            state_machine:
#                graph: sylius_order_checkout
#                transition: select_payment
#            redirect:
#                route: sylius_shop_checkout_complete
#                parameters: []

sylius_shop_checkout_complete:
    path: /complete
    methods: [GET, PUT]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.order:updateAction
        _sylius:
            event: summary
            flash: false
            template: SyliusShopBundle:Checkout:complete.html.twig
            repository:
                method: find
                arguments: [expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart()]
            state_machine:
                graph: sylius_order_checkout
                transition: complete
            redirect:
                route: sylius_shop_order_pay
                parameters:
                    paymentId: expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart().getLastNewPayment().getId()
            form:
                type: sylius_checkout_complete
                options:
                    validation_groups: 'sylius_checkout_complete'
```

I cleared my cache, and the two additional steps are removed from checkout from what I can tell. Clicking next on the address step does send me to the final 'checkout' step, it just 302's me right back to the address step without an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can spot one bug in your config file:

```
states:
    cart: ~
    addressed: ~
    completed: ~
transitions:
    address:
        from: [cart, addressed]
        to: addressed
    complete:
        from: [payment_selected] # <- here
        to: completed
```

The complete transition should be done from `addressed` state instead of `payment_selected` (which does not exist in your configuration). It should resolve your problem.

You are also right, that default method resolvers are not documented yet. There are two classes responsible for assigning a default shipping and payment methods to order (DefaultPaymentMethodResolver and DefaultShippingMethodResolver). Both will assign the first available method. It should be an expected behaviour if you have only one method available. But feel free to override these classes to provide your custom logic :)

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly my issue and solved it! :D